# JQuery - Button Click not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

We have a Search textbox and search button in our page. We need to fire the server side button click event when the user enters a search string and hits enter. The code is in the user control(ascx). 
The code is....

ascx

```
<td class="search_txt_box">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchBox" class="frmdefault" runat="server"
               MaxLength="100" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td class="new_search_btn">
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearchHelp" class="ovalbutton" runat="server"
            OnClick="btnSearchHelp_Click">
    <span id="spanBtnTxt" runat="server" class="btn_arrow_space"></span>
  </asp:LinkButton>
</td>
```

JQuery

```
  (function ($) {
     $(function () {
          $('input[id$="txtSearchBox"]').keypress(function (e) {
        var keyCode;

        if (window.event) keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e) keyCode = e.which;
        else return true;

        if (keyCode == 13) {
            //alert("Out - Clicked");
            //alert($('[id*="btnSearchHelp"]').attr('id'));

            $('[id*="btnSearchHelp"]').click();
            return false;
            //$('[id*="btnSearchHelp"]').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            //    alert('this is the click');
            //    e.preventDefault();
            //});
        }
    });
     });
  } (jQuery));
```

ascx.cs

```
protected void btnSearchHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //handle search click
}
```

We tried looking for answers in forums and tried few but none of them worked. "Out-Clicked" alert and next alert with button's dynamic id is displayed but after that nothing happens. We wrote an inline Jquery function but even thats not called. Can anyone please let us know what we are doing wrong here?

Comment: Replace txtSearchBox with <%=txtSearchBox.ClientID %>.  Client side the control I'd generate differently.

Comment: @Nps Thats not the issue since the event is called as it is since i can see the alert boxes. But I agree with your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If changing the markup isn't out of the question you could wrap the search input in a form element and use the [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on that form.

That way both hitting Return AND clicking "Search" button would fire the event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, wouldnt that mean nested forms? Arent we supposed to not do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here:

```
(function ($) { 

      //you are trying to capture domready function in this
      //This is actually a way to author a jQuery Plugin

} (jQuery));
      //  ^-------------------------
      // although you have put one extra paranthesis ")" at the closing
      // this doesn't matter this won't work if you remove it though
```

`If you are using different js libraries` and you are `facing issues of conflict` in libraries then you have to `save your '$' sign` in this closure as above. although same thing `you can do with your doc ready` function as `this way`:

```
jQuery(function($){

   // I just used a simple alert function to test
   // You can do your stuff here.
   alert('123');
});
```

Here you are enclosing your `$` sign. This way you will be able to not to get conflicted by other libraries.

You can findout more here:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of using link button.

When link button is rendered, it will be like

```
<a id="btnSearchHelp" class="ovalbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnSearchHelp','')"><span id="spanBtnTxt">
```

Click event from JS will trigger the handler that is defined in **onclick** attribute. In your case href attribute is defined and href attribute wont be triggered.

Options:

1) You can use asp:button instead of asp:link button.

2) use the below code instead of your $('[id*="btnSearchHelp"]').click();

```
var submitButton = $('[id*="btnSearchHelp"]');
var events = submitButton.data('events');
                if (submitButton.get(0).onclick) {
                    eval(submitButton.get(0).onclick());
                }
                if (events != null && events.click != null && events.click.length > 0) {
                    $(submitButton).trigger(events.click);
                    $.each(events.click, function (index, evt) {
                        evt.handler();
                    });
                }

                if ($.trim(submitButton.attr("href")) != "") {
                    if (submitButton.attr("href").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("javascript:") != -1) {
                        eval(submitButton.attr("href"));
                    }
                }
```

Hope it helps you.